# Emacs: Changing the location of auto-save files

Tags: emacs

I've currently got:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

in my `.emacs`, but that doesn't seem to have changed where auto-save files get saved (it has changed where backup files get saved. `M-x describe-variable` shows that `temporary-file-directory` is set to `/tmp/`, but when I edit a file called `testing.md` and have unsaved changes, I get a file called `.#testing.md` in the same directory. How can I make that file go somewhere else (e.g. `/tmp/`)?

I've had no luck with [these suggestions](http://snarfed.org/gnu_emacs_backup_files), so any suggestions welcome!

If it helps, I'm on GNU Emacs 23.3.1, running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These files are not autosaves, they're lock files.  Try to `ls -l` them, and you'll see that they're symbolic links that point to bogus filenames which are actually the username+pid of the editing process.  AFAIK, there's no way to customize that.  (The whole point is to avoid problems when two different users edit the same file -- if one changes the lockfile location they won't know about each other's edits.)  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651169).

(BTW, using `/tmp` to save backups is really not a good idea unless you're sure that you're the only user on the machine.)

Answer (score 2):

```
; auto save path
(defvar autosave-dir (concat "~/auto-save" "/"))
(make-directory autosave-dir t)
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `(("\\(?:[^/]*/\\)*\\(.*\\)" ,(concat autosave-dir "\\1") t)))
```

OS : win7
Ver: emacs 23.4